# When I click one like button all the like buttons are liked why?

Tags: php, wordpress, button, plugins

I am currently working with Accessing json using php in wordpress. For displaying like button I am using the shortcode **echo do_shortcode('[likebtn]');**
inside the loop,but unfortunately when i click one like buttons all the like buttons are liked.

```
if( ! empty($data1)) {
    echo "Fetching from  " .$data->City." Server".'<br>';
    foreach($data1 as $js){
        echo $js->AIPlatform;
        
        foreach($js->NewsFeed as $pip){
            
            foreach($pip->data as $pr){
                foreach($pr->data as $ar){
                echo '<br>'.$pr->ClusterID.'<br>';
                    echo '<b>'.'<a href="'.$ar->Url.   '" target="_blank";    >'.$ar->text.'</a>'.'<br>'.'</b>';
                    
                    echo '<div class="image">'.'<img src="'.$ar->Image.'"/>'.'</div>'.'<p>'.$ar->Title.'<br>'.'<br>'.'<br>'.'<br>'.'<br>'.'<br>'.'<br>';
                    echo do_shortcode('[likebtn]');
                    
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }

        
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure to post as much details when you post a question. I believe you are using the plugin named [LikeBtn](https://wordpress.org/plugins/likebtn-like-button/). If so, as per [the documentation](https://likebtn.com/en/wordpress-like-button-plugin#shortcode), it talks about a parameter called `identifier` :

> Button `identifier` parameter is used for statistics analysis. If
> `identifier` parameter is not specified, post ID is used.
>
> If specifying custom `identifier` you will see button identifier in
> statistics and most liked content widget instead of post title. You
> also will be unable to sort posts by likes. **Make sure to specify a
> unique identifier for each like button using identifier parameter,
> otherwise all the buttons will reflect the same number of likes.**

So am guessing that your code is run on a Page or Post, which makes the plugin auto fetch that Page/Post's id as `identifier` since you are not explicitly passing it to the shortcode. Hence, all like buttons are getting updated at once when you click one of it!

What you have to do is, pass a unique id as `identifier` to that shortcode (in that loop). I think you can pass `$pr->ClusterID` as the `identifier`, but I don't know whether it's a unique id or not. If not, you have to brainstorm for what to be passed as `identifier` which would be unique (no repetitions on that same Page/Post)

**EDIT**

So, you can change your echo line to something like this:

```
echo do_shortcode('[likebtn identifier="'. $pr->ClusterID .'"]');
```

Comment: Hello@ Ajilesh B chandran I am using the LikeBtn plugin that you have already mentioned. $pr->ClusterId id is an unique identifier . How should i use that identifier in the program? What changes to be done in that shortcode line?

Comment: @PradeeshwarM edited my answer. Please check